# build a rss feed

Tags: php, mysql, rss, feed

I'm trying to build a dynamic rss feed file, for the first time, for a news page to a site.

so I have the following code

```
<?php
    header("Content-Type: application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8");

    echo'
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <title>My Site RSS feed</title>
            <guid>http://example.com/media/news.php</guid>
                    <link>http://www.exemple.com/mediacenter/news.php</link>
                     <description>This is an example RSS feed</description>
                    <language>en-US</language>              
    ';

    include('../misc/session.php'); // to get the language selected by user
    include('../includes/connection.php'); //connection to DB

    $idLang = $_SESSION['idLang'];


    $query = mysql_query("SELECT FROM tbl_news WHERE lang_id = '$idLang'");

    while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
        echo"
            <item>
                <title>".$rs['l_tltle']."</title>
                <link>a href='http://www.exemple.com/media/news.php'</link>
                <description><!CDATA['".$rs['l_text']."']></description>
            </item>
        ";
    }
    echo'
    </channel>
    </rss>
    ';
?>
```

In my index.php file, before  i got this line:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="MySite RSS Feed" href="http://mysite.com/rssfeed/rss.php" />
```

When I click on the icon with Firefox it should open a page with the google reader page, like it happens in other sites, but in my case it open a  pop up window to save a file. In chrome I have an [this extensison](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rss-feed-reader/pnjaodmkngahhkoihejjehlcdlnohgmp) and it detect that there's a feed. But it doesnt list any news.

Can anyone help me?? What is missing??

Thanks

Comment: header('Content-type: text/xml'); is this enough?

Comment: This would help.. Please check http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-create-an-rss-feed-for-your-site-from-scratch/

Comment: @peterK : Did you get the solution of this issue? I am getting same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems.

First is in the query. It is missing the * after SELECT. 
Second mistake is in the second line. The `<?xml version="1.0"...` must be in the same line as the single quote. Like this `echo' <?xml version="1.0" ...` otherwise it gives validation errors and the browser can't reed the feed.

Feel free to give more suggestions